# How use "using" in my Connection Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use using for `SqlConnection` in my code like this

```
using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection())
```

But I have used `dictionary` for several connections inside a `Connections` class. Here is the code for my `Connections` class.

```
public static class Connections
{
    public static string BillReport { get; set; }
    public static string DuesReport { get; set; }
    public static string GeneralReport { get; set; }
    public static string PendingReport { get; set; }
    public static string RadiologyReport { get; set; }
    public static string HistoReport { get; set; }
    public static string SMSAPI { get; set; }
    public static string SenderId { get; set; }
    public static string SMSUserName { get; set; }
    public static string SMSContent { get; set; }
    public static string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public static string CompanyMobile { get; set; }

    private static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> _Connection = new Dictionary<string, SqlConnection>();
    public static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> Connection
    {
        get { return _Connection; }
        set { _Connection = value; }
    } 
     public static void Init(string Name)
     {
         string user = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();

         //INIT YOUR CONNECTION PROPERTY HERE
         if (!Connection.ContainsKey(user))
         {
             Connection.Add(user, new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString));
         }
         else
         {
             //if (Connection[user] == null)
             //{
                 Connection[user] = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
             //}
         }
     }
}
```

So whenever I have to use connection I write this...

```
Connections.Connection[UserName].Open();
```

But how can I use this with `Using`

Comment: There is typically no need for you to cache connections in your code. Unless you have performed measurements that with certainty have concluded that creating connection objects is indeed a bottle neck, the only thing you get here is added complexity.

Comment: Your class itself is the bug. You don't need that dictionary at all. Opening a new connection does *NOT* cost you anything thanks to connection pooling.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need to cache connections in the first place? Why not use the standard practice of creating a new connection object? You can create a small helper method to retrieve connection *strings* based on name if you want

Comment: Best case with this class - your web site crashes because you tried to `.Open()` an already disposed connection. Worst case - you try to replace connections, forget to dispose them properly and end up with slowly decreasing performance due to open transactions, locks etc that's hard to detect. In all cases you'll use a *lot* more connections than needed. Connection pooling could reset and reuse the same connection for multiple users. Now, each user will open yet another connection

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos My application runs on localhost where multiple computers access it through IP. So I used dictionary. is it not the good Idea ?
Please suggest me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is this the reason my application is gets slow after some time ?   and it's performance gets very down in low configuration computer.

Comment: Opening a new connection is expensive (can take seconds), which is why connection pooling is used. Another problem is that long running connections accumulate locks, especially share locks, as you read from various tables. The server doesn't know that you don't care about that table you opened 15 seconds ago, so the locks are kept.

Comment: All this is solved with connection pooling. Connection pooling means that once you close a connection it's *not* really closed. It's reset releasing all locks, and placed in a connection pool, available for reuse. This means that creating a new SqlConnection object isn't expensive any more, so you can close connections immediatelly. This way, you avoid accumulating locks. That's why you don't see any attempts to cache connection objects in any ADO.NET or web example.

Comment: Thank you for great knowledge. Tell me me one more thing. My way consumes lot of memory ?   Actually when I run my project after sometime the performance becomes get down specially in low configuration computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to, just use `Connections.Connection[UserName]`. That returns the same `SqlConnection`. However that will dispose it. Your pattern/design is flawed because ADO.NET has connection pooling.

You could also add your own wrapping object that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: That would result in cached disposed connections. The OP's class just isn't useful thanks to connection pooling. There is no need to cache connections

Comment: The best guidance is "just don't do this"