# What is wrong with my code for SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my web.config I declared many connectionstrings based on different database like this...

```
<add name="connect15-16" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database15-16;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect16-17" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database16-17;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect17-18" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database17-18;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect18-19" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database18-19;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect19-20" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database19-20;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
```

At the time of login, user has to select appropriate database then based on that selected database software connects to the desired database.

I have created a global class which connects user to desired database like this

```
public static class Connections
{   
     public static SqlConnection Connection {get; set;}    
     public static void Init(string Name)
     {         
         Connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
                              .ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
     }
}
```

This was working fine. But When I run it on localhost and multiple user access it from different computers through ip then the main problem begins.

If User1 connects to connect15-16 and after some time user2 connects to connect16-17 then the value of Connection variable overites and User1 connects with connect16-17 automatically.

To resolve this issue I made some changes to my `Connections` class and used `dictionary` for creating separate connection for different users. Here is my new `Connections` class

```
public static class Connections
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> _Connection = new Dictionary<string, SqlConnection>();
        public static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> Connection
        {
            get { return _Connection; }
            set { _Connection = value; }
        }
        public static void Init(string Name)
        {
            string user=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
            if (!Connection.ContainsKey(user))
            {
                Connection.Add(user, new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString));
            }
            else
            {
                if (Connection[user] == null)
                {
                    Connection[user] = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Now everywhere I use the following code for opening and closing connection.

```
Connections.Connection[UserName].Open();
Connections.Connection[UserName].Close();
```

My problem has resolved successfully but new problem begins. The performance of my software gets very very down. Some experts told me that this is because of my `Connections` class because there are lots of disposed connections which takes too much memory.

Please suggest me what changes need to my `Connections` class for better performance.

Comment: your code is not thread safe, Init method will crash eventually.

Comment: @VolkanSeçkinAkbayır Please can you brief ?  How my code is not safe and how Init method will crash ?

Comment: I would recommend for your problem with users self overriding connection strings to implement Factory design pattern at DAL level: http://www.primaryobjects.com/2007/11/16/implementing-a-database-factory-pattern-in-c-asp-net/

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi you have a static method that writes to a static dictionary without a locking mechanism. When you use multiple threads , it will try to override your created sql connection and try to store same key to dictionary.

Comment: You **ALREADY ASKED THAT QUESTION YESTERDAY**. The answers are the same. Bad class. Don't use. Don't cache connections. Don't repeat the question. .NET didn't changes since yesterday

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos I have not much experience. So I asked you some simple questions in comment yesterday but you didn't answer. So I posted a new question here. But doubts are still not clear.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi I did answer. If you don't understand the concepts, you should find a tutorial. SO isn't the place to ask for ADO.NET tutorials. *Don't* try to solve non-existent problems - why are you caching connections **at all**?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please can you explain with an example ?  It'll  be a great help. I understand that I have to dispose the connection as soon as possible. But when I am trying to use `using` in my code it's not working. So tell me what should I need to change in my `Connections` class ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - what part are you not understanding? The only thing you could use `Connections` for is as a factory to return a new `SqlConnection` instance initialized with the appropriate connection string but that is it. Do not store the connection, it should not have any type of state. The caller is responsible for disposing the connection's it requests.

Comment: @Igor - You mean to say. My first `Connections` class is perfect (mentioned in my question).  ? There I am not storing any connection.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - I am not saying that at all, if [this is what you are referring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657437/how-use-using-in-my-connection-class) to you are storing the connection and it has state and that is not recommended.

Comment: Still not understand :( . I think my basic knowledge about Ado.Net is poor. I wish If someone explain to me with an example. I can understand that I am storing the connection which is not recommended. But what is the solution of that ?  What should I need to change in my `Connections` class. Not one is telling that. :(

Comment: People are feeling more comfortable in `Voting Down` my question instead of giving an example.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi people are getting annoyed that despite offering links and examples, like Igor did, or explaining multiple times that your entire class is meaningless and showing you why, you keep asking about examples. *Did* you check *any* of Igor's links? They offer full explanations and examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reaction to your code this, scrap the design and create your connections on an as needed basis and then destroy them as soon as you are done with them.

Example:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(/*connection string from app/web.config*/))
{
  // use the connection
}
```

Why?

ADO.NET for Sql Server uses connection pooling under water. `SqlConnection` instances automatically reuse an available connection from the pool when you create a new `SqlConnection` instance. Because of this there is no real performance gain by trying to reuse `SqlConnection` instances. For more information on how the pool is managed by ADO.NET see [Sql Server Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

The recommendation is to create a `SqlConnection` when you need it wrapped in a `using` block so it is disposed as soon as you are done. Keep your `SqlConnection` short lived. This ensures that no connection stay open longer then necessary and ensures there is no possibility for race conditions to occur by trying to share/reuse connections.

---

> I wish If someone explain to me with an example...

An example of your code refactored. Replace your `Connections` class with `ConnectionFactory`, note that there is no state being persisted in memory. It creates a new connection and returns it, nothing more. The consumer gets the connection and disposes of it when finished inside the `using` block.

*ConnectionFactory.cs*

```
public static class ConnectionFactory
{
    public static SqlConnection Create(string Name)
    {
        // todo: add some checking to ensure that Name parameter is not null/empty and that there is a corresponding entry in the app/web config
        return new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

*SomeCallingMethod.cs*

```
public void GetSomethingFromStore()
{
    using(var connection = ConnectionFactory.Create("connect15-16"))
    {
        // do some db work
    }
}
```

Comment: Everywhere I used Try, Catch and Finally. Inside Finally I close the connection. Is it not enough ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - you are storing the connection instance in a static dictionary which is not recommended. Reading the code above you can easily make the assumption you are not disposing your connections. Create a new instance when needed and ensure it is disposed as soon as you are done.

Comment: Side note: connection pool is not managed by sql server, it in fact has no idea about such thing at all. Connection pool is managed by clients (so, for example, by .NET sql server client library). So not sure what you mean by "a setting that is set to true/on by default when you deploy sql server".

Comment: @Evk - thanks, I learned something new.

Comment: @Igor you should know the OP asked [the same question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657437/how-use-using-in-my-connection-class), got the same answer you gave in the comments (by me).

Comment: @Evk not quite - the server must support resetting a connection, otherwise connection pooling wouldn't release shared locks and other resources required for an actively used connection. SQL Server does. If you check with SQL Server Profiler, you'll see a `reset connection` event whenever a connection is disposed. OTOH connection pooling is supported by most types of databases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos don't see how it contradicts what I said - connection pool is still managed by client and server still has no idea about client pools.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - see the updated example. I really hope this clears it up for you, do not make it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @Igor Thank you so very much for your help. Let me check it. I will update you soon.